# Two research areas of interest for faculty position

Tags: job-search, interview

I have a PhD in heat transfer area and postdoc experience in biomolecular simulations. I like both of the disciplines and published more than 20 journal articles in both fields together. When I appear for faculty interviews, which area should I focus more? Since I have done a significant amount of work in both fields, my mind is not letting me to disregard biomolecular simulations from the presentation. At the same time within the given 50 mins, talking about both distinct topics is challenging both for me and the audience. I am unable to make a decision, please guide me. (I have a BSME and currently Assistant Professor looking to switch to R1 university in mechanical department).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you should tailor the talk to the job at hand. The job description should be a good guide. Failing that, look at what the current faculty do, and are therefor interested in.

The only exception would seem to be a job in a department that was explicitly interested in expanding research areas, in which case, probably talk more about which area you'd like to focus on, without ignoring the other.

Comment: Thank you, it helps. I don't know why I never put the job description in the picture. It makes more sense now.